# Event to listen on hovering on the bar in bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, bar-chart

I am new to front end development.

Does any one come across a bar graph plugin which when we hover on any of the bars will popup a modal with some  table in which some hyperlinks related to the bar will be shown.

I want to show some html table related to bar when i hover on each of the bars.

How can i create an event to listen on hovering over the bar

Also i am wondering how can i make this dynamic. In all the demos i see the graph values are hard coded. How can i load this data with some content i get back from server.

Thanks

Comment: Which plugin are you looking at? You mention demos.

Comment: I am looking at high charts... Some one edited the question and removed the links. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/

Comment: @mikakun i noticed this which will do all i want for free. http://www.geertdedeckere.be/shop/graphup/download/demo2/. basically it asks for a table. So i can give it a dynamic table and i can create event on table row hovering.